Insight on site geometrics for collisions
I’m analyzing safety issues along New Street in Burlington, Ontario, and have identified several locations with high collision rates. Here are the details:
Intersections:
    New @ Cumberland: Out of 28 collisions, 11 were angle collisions.
    New @ Pine Cove: Out of 12 collisions, 7 were angle collisions.

Midblock Section:
    New Street between Dynes & Cumberland: Mainly sideswipes followed closely by rear-ends

I have examined geometric features such as curb radii and vertical curves using tools like Google Earth, but I haven’t pinpointed a clear cause for these collision patterns. I've included some preliminary work below.


Can anyone provide insights into how specific geometric design elements or road features might contribute to these types of collisions at these locations? Any advice on aspects I might have overlooked would be greatly appreciated.

Have you considered that site geometrics might not be an issue & that maybe driver carelessness might be a bigger factor? I notice the Gary Allan High School & Brant Children's Center are located on the supposedly collision prone section of New Street. Could these be contributing elements? Other things to consider are the times when the collisions occurred & how heavy was the traffic flow on New Street at those times & are the intersections busy intersections? Does New Street have traffic turning lanes at those intersections? Is Sun glare an issue?

So Burlington, Ontario needs to be crossed off my bucket list?

have you visited the locations?
